# Treasure - rare, very rare and ultra rare item drops rate in The International treasures

Tags: dota-2

Few weeks ago start The International 2018 (TI). With battle pass we can get some treasures which should contain mythical items. Non-rare items have drop rate in first treasure is 1/6, and second is 1/5(- already owned item), third is 1/4(-2 already owned items) etc. This year I write with a lot of players complains (1000+ battle pass level) they did not get any ultra rare item, and last year after level 1000+ they have atleast one or more ultra rare items. Number of treasures from level 1 to 1000 did not rapidy change. Last year was public chances to drop for Chines players, but not for rest of world. But we know it is simillar as in China. Do we have some information how big is chance to ultra rare items from treasures? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another day of searching on gamepedia/dota2 (source) I found this information about drops:

Again as last year the following escalating drop rates for this treasure. These rates may not apply to **non**-Chinese servers.

Rare: after 10 chests chances for rare are 1/4 or 25%

Very Rare: after 10 chests chances for very rare are 1/7 or 14.28%

Ultra Rare: after 23 chests chances for ultra rare are 1/10 or 10%

Cosmically rare: 1/250000 or 0.0004%

Also Rylais blessing odds:

Bundle: 70%

Treasure: 18.9%

Courier: 7.5%

Announcer: 3%

Immortal Treasure: 0.5%

Arcana: 0.1%